# how to replace a word with in contains() Method form a JtextPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, replace, contains

Well, I'm trying to replace a word by using contains() Method:

```
String z = tfB.getText().toString();
String show = textPane.getText().toString();
   if(show.contains(z)){

     // how I specify the word that were found and change it without 
        effecting anything with in that line

   }
```

well what I main by that:

What I'm trying to do is get the value from the user.
then search if it found replace it with something. For example:

```
 String x = "one two three four five";
```

It should set the textPane to `"one two 3 four five"`
or

```
"one two 3-three-3 four five"
```

could any one please tell me how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to check if it exist before you try to replace.

Comment: contains doesn't replace. contains only tells you if some text contains a string. By reading the javadoc of String, you should be able to find methods useful for replacing. The documentation is the programmer's best friend. Read it. It has been written for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do is get the value from the user. then search if it found replace it with something.

Don't use the `contains()` method because you will need to search the text twice:

1. once to see if the text is found in the string
2. again to replace the text with a new string.

Instead, use the `String.indexof(...)` method. It will return the index of the text IF it is found in the String.

Then you should replace the text directly in the Document of the text pane, not in the String itself. So the code would be something like:

```
int length = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
String text = textPane.getDocument().getText(0, length);
String search = "abc...";
int offset = text.indexOf(search);

if (offset != -1)
{
    textPane.setSelectionStart(offset);
    textPane.setSelectionEnd(offset + search.length();
    textPane.replaceSelection("123...");
}
```

Also, not that you get the text from the Document, not the text pane. This is to make sure the offsets are correct when you replace the text in the Document. Check out [Text and New Lines](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information on why this is important.

Comment: @dragon3002, you're welcome, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the question has been solved.